# Display divs in row with line return if too long

Tags: html, css

I have N div of the same fixed size (both width and height).
I want to display them in lines with a fixed sapcing vetween each other.
I N elements do not fit in one line, creates another line.
It would look like this:[image: one line display with line return]

I tried with `display flex` but it does not go to a new line.
I tried with grid but the number of columns depends on how many items can fit in the width.

```css
  .item{
    width: 300px; 
    height: 400px; 
    background-color: grey; 
    margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Aleno</h1>

  <div style="display: flex;" >
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: probably a duplicate, use `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the following attribute `flex-wrap` so that your elements create a new line automatically you can see more about that attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).
Of course you'll need it on your parent element.

```css
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Comment: @VinceM You're welcome, Don't forget to set it as the answer if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You should give `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the parent element which will arrange the child element in the given width of the container and prevents overflow by creating a new row/column for the remaining elements.